# help becoming a research assistant

Tags: research-undergraduate, teaching-assistant, research-assistantship, psychology

This is probably me overthinking a lot but I really don't want to screw this up. There was a flyer sent to me by my adviser for a research assistant opening for one of the psych professors on campus. The flyer says basic info such as what the research is about, requirements, and benefits. On the bottom of the flyer it says please contact if interested. I am not sure what to email the professor besides "hello I am interested in your study and I would like to join as one of your research assistants" something like that. What else should I add?? or should it simply be something basic like that. Also she is looking for students that have a 3.0 gpa or higher. I have a 2.7 gpa but I am really working hard to get a high gpa taking many classes. I want to let her know this and let her know not to look at my gpa but my hard work and determination. I have a bad gpa from my mistakes I made in my first year at community college. Well any advice helps I just overthink a lot and I really want to become an assistant and start helping my career little by little.

Answer (score 3):

You’re applying for a job. Treat it like any other job application: write a cover letter, and attach your CV. If you aren’t sure how to do those things, consider doing a google search or asking your university’s career office.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the email to ask for an appointment to visit her in person. Or, if she has regular office hours, to just say that you will stop by at the next opportunity. You can't guess what she wants to hear, other than your interest and a few words about your background if it matches what she has already said about the position.

But, you will need to meet with her eventually in any case. Better to do it soon. She won't hire you based on just an email.